# Is investigator Murray a Russian spy in Stranger Things 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, stranger-things

Many ideas just come to my mind after watching the S2E5&6. This private, free-lance investigator seems strangely mysterious to me, obviously when [Murray](http://strangerthings.wikia.com/wiki/Murray_Bauman) stores a lot of Vodka in his refrigerator. And he didn't want the couple (Nancy and Jonathan) to look for him again at all.

> If you needa reach me again, DON'T!

In short:

- The S2E6's name is *The Spy*.
- Murray stores and drinks lots of Vodkas.
- He doesn't want Nancy and Jonathan to reach him again.

Is there any possibility that he's a spy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Till the end of the season 2, it isn't stated or hinted that he is a Russian spy. It's just fan theories. He could be, but this part is pure speculation for now.

However, the points you refer really don't hint that he is a Russian spy. To explain it better, I will go through all points one by one.

> - The S2E6's name is The Spy.

This episode title is not really referring to him, but the Shadow Monster. Since it is inside the mind of Will Byers, both can see through each other's mind which means that both can spy on each other. When Will tells about the shadow monster to Mike, Mike asks if he can spy on it.

From S02E05,

> **Mike:** Good? Just think about it, Will. **You're like a spy now. A superspy. Spying on the shadow monster.** If you know what he's seeing and feeling maybe that's how we can stop him. Maybe all of this is happening for a reason.
>
> **Will:** You really think so?
>
> **Mike:** Yeah. Yeah, I really do.
>
> **Will:** What if he figures out we're spying on him? - What if he spies back?

<sub>[Script Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=stranger-things-2016&episode=s02e05)</sub>

And that's exactly what happens in the next episode.

> **Will:** They upset him. They shouldn't have done that. They shouldn't have upset him.
>
> **Mike:** **The Spy. The Spy!**

<sub>[Script Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=stranger-things-2016&episode=s02e06)</sub>

So, it's clear that the title is not referring to Murray, but the shadow monster.

> - Murray stores and drinks lots of Vodkas.

Vodka is a popular drink across the world, which was originated from Russia. However, it is available in many countries, and there is no such rule that only Russian can drink vodka. Therefore, him drinking lots of vodka doesn't really make him a Russian spy.

> - He doesn't want Nancy and Jonathan to reach him again.

Well, he is a detective and doing his work to find Barb (Nancy's friend). Detective work requires a lot of focus and it should be done very quietly. If Jonathan and Nancy try to contact him again, he'd not be able to focus on his work.

After going into details of all these points, these really don't hint or prove that he is a Russian spy.

Comment: It may be that Murry was red hearing.

Comment: If Murray is not a spy, he won't be aware of the existence of the lab (which is publicly known as Hawkins Power and Light). But the isolation to focus on detective's job sounds reasonable. I agree with you about that episode's title, it's supposed to aim to the shadow monster. But about the Vodka, I think the cold war has some effects on the import of Russian products, and I believe it's hard to find a Russian product in the US (in the 1980s). I'm not American nor Russian, so I'm not very sure about this.

Comment: America is a land of immigrants, many traditions, foods and drinks from other countries were brought to it's shores by those people. There were US only brands of vodka in the 1980s, there is no problem with a US citizen drinking vodka. Other brands existed in other parts of the world Smirnoff is one of them.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smirnoff I sometimes drank that brand in the UK in the 1980s..

Comment: Re the telling Nancy/Jonathan to not reach him again: I don't think that it's due to his wanting to focus on Barb. They told him the untold story of Barb so there's nothing to focus on. Plus, I've always read him as a crackpot journalist and it was his paranoia that was telling the kids to keep away.

Comment: This answer should be updated now with season 3 and Murray's ability to speak Russian... :)